# gradle -v does not work and gives java errors

Tags: gradle

I can't seem to get gradle to install on work on opensuse 13.2.

Installed by:

```
sudo unzip -oq gradle-2.2.1-all.zip -d /opt/gradle
sudo ln -sfn gradle-2.2.1 /opt/gradle/latest
export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/latest
export PATH=$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

running gradle:

```
$gradle -v
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.gradle.util.CollectionUtils
       at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.14)
       at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultClassPath.<init>(DefaultClassPath.java:37)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.EffectiveClassPath.<init>(EffectiveClassPath.java:32)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.<init>(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:61)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.<init>(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:55)
       at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:44)
       at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
       at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:/opt/gradle/gradle-2.2.1/lib/gradle-launcher-2.2.1.jar], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.14)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.14)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.14)
       at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.14)
       ...7 more
```

Comment: Have you double-checked that your commands are correct? Shouldn't it be `/opt/gradle/gradle-2.2.1` on the second line?

Comment: Use some standard Java implementation like OpenJDK or the one provided by Oracle and not GCJ.

Comment: Try installing with [GVM](http://gvmtool.net/)

Comment: thanks @Radim, the stupid things always get me. I'm using openJDK.

Comment: @vcarvalho I will be looking into GVM. That looks promising as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the symlink in /usr/bin?

Like this:

**sudo ln -s /opt/gradle/latest/bin/gradle /usr/bin/gradle**

It worked for me in openSuse 13.2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure gradle is using Java 1.8

```
> $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
```

Should return

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.8.0) (build 1.8.0_171-b11 suse-24.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

My box had $JAVA_HOME linked to Java 1.5